# Extracting record from table skip record of other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Having two tables
1. Parent Users
2. Child Users

[image]

Child User table also has records of Parent Users.
I want an output of All Childs only.

Comment: output required is all records Highlighted in green.

Comment: Please, show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to take one more column in **child User** with flag `( 1 for parant user, 0 for child user )` like:

```
          child users
-------------------------------------
| id  |  name  |  by_id   |  flag   |
-------------------------------------
| 1   |  x     |  1       |   1     |
| 2   |  a     |  1       |   0     |
| 3   |  b     |  1       |   0     |
| 4   |  z     |  3       |   1     |
| 5   |  c     |  3       |   0     |
| 6   |  y     |  2       |   1     |
| 7   |  d     |  2       |   0     |
| 8   |  e     |  1       |   0     |
```

**To get all child entries:**

```
SELECT id, name FROM child_users WHERE flag = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to solve this using a `LEFT JOIN` of the child table against the parent table:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ChildUsers t1
LEFT JOIN ParentUsers t2
    ON t1.by_id = t2.id AND
       t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

The trick here is the `WHERE` clause `WHERE t2.name IS NULL`, which will discard any records which correspond to parents.

As @SHAZ pointed out in his comment, the only way to identify a child entry as being a potential parent is by using the `name` field.  In the event that a parent and child who are different happen to have the same, then the child could be incorrectly filtered out from the result set.

**Demo Here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: What if parent and child name are same? @Tim B.

Comment: @SHAZ Then we have a problem.  I added a check using the `by_id` in the child table, but even this isn't foolproof if a parent and child still have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name,a.by_id from
(select id,name,by_id from tbl_child) as a

left JOIN

(select id, name from tbl_parent)as b

on a.name = b.name where b.name is null
```

It return an output as you need.